# Extracting sampled Time Points

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, sampling

I have a matlab Curve from which i would like to plot and  find Concentration values at  17 different time samples

Following is the curve  from which i would like to extract Concentration values at 17 different time points

[image: first]

following are the time points in minutes

```
t = 0,0.25,0.50,1,1.5,2,3,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49. minutes samples
```

Following is the Function which i have written to plot the above graph

```
function c_t = output_function_constrainedK2(t, a1, a2, a3,b1,b2,b3,td, tmax,k1,k2,k3)



K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+k3);
K_2   = (k1*k3)/(k2+k3);
DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);


c_t = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);


c_t(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

ind = (t >= tmax);


c_t(ind)= conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');



plot(t,c_t);
axis([0 50  0 1400]);
xlabel('Time[mins]');
ylabel('concentration [Mbq]');
title('Model :Constrained K2');
end
```

If possible, Kindly please suggest me some idea how i could possibly alter the above function so that i can come up with concentration values at 17 different time points stated above

Following  are the input values that i have used to come up with the curve

```
 output_function_constrainedK2(0:0.1:50,2501,18500,65000,0.5,0.7,0.3,3,8,0.014,0.051,0.07)
```

Comment: Why not just put in the time points that you want as the `t` input argument when you call the function?

Comment: @David: Pardon me, I am beginner to matlab,what i have is time t=50 minutes which is scanning time and i cannot possibly change that value, yes i can simply put different t values and call the function but its not acceptable as per my current work guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you concentration values at the time points you wanted. You will have to put this inside the `output_function_constrainedK2` function so that you can access the variables `t` and `c_t`.

```
T=[0 0.25 0.50 1 1.5 2 3 4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49];
concentration=interp1(t,c_t,T)
```

Comment: Dear Sir,Let me rephrase my problem more accurately,before that what you have stated in your answer is exactly true and i have done the same process for obtaining the values at different time intervals....What i require is to write a function or a code which does exact same work, i firmly understand that your way is absolutely right,but as part of my project i have to write a function or a code which extracts the concentration values from the curve at different time points.This is my problem

Comment: I edited my answer, but I am still not sure what you are really asking, or whether you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is about sampling the data , if i run the original function with the given input values i obtain 501 sampling points, now i would like to create 17 different time Frames(Frame based signal processing method)...and your method of working is absolutely right,but as per the project i have to write a "for loop" to extract different time samples..there is nothing wrong in your way of solving it, i have done the same way,but when i work upon for loop i am incurring errors,so i have posted this question..Kindly suggest me how i can approach same problem through for loop,if possible

Comment: i have  Accepted your answer, thanks for your help, if possible kindly let me know how i can approach same problem through for loop..I have solved the problem initially in the same processes through interpolation,but as per the exercise which i have to solve in this project i have to write for loop and i am incurring errors

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Where is the `for` loop supposed to go and why is it necessary?

Comment: Dear sir, I have one more question which is not mentioned in the query which i have posted...for the above code i would like to Optimize the value of k3,the initialization value for k3 which i have used is k3=0.07 in the above code, if possible could you please give me some idea how i can optimize k3 value from the above function, i have never used "optimization tool box"..any sample examples would be greatly helpful,i have to work on this whole night now

Comment: Ask a new question for that, with a very small example of a problem like your real one, that is small and self-contained. What you are asking now is quite different to the question you posted here.

Comment: Dear sir, I am working on assignment,so as per the rules i have to extract the concentration values using for loop,for loop must be before index ind,but this is just minute aspect of Sample assignment,i have approached the sample like you did.if possible could you please let me know how i can optimize the value of K3 from the above code with the initialization value k3=0.07

Comment: :I have asked a new question with the example of the problem  question is stated here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400815/parameter-optimization-matlab..kindly let me know if any thing is unclear,please dont down vote the question